# Set google sheet file owner

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

From my site, I create a sheet by the google sheet api. I need to give the 'owner' permission to another user by his email address. The question is: how to do this?
The best way is to make this thing by clear sheet api - it's like create instantly for one user only.

Or I need to use a few APIs: sheet api and drive api, and get a few tokens for it? (( right now, from sheets api I had 'DRIVE' permission ))

Comment: Okay, I got it. I do it by both APIs: create the sheet by sheet API, and make the file writer by drive API.
PS: you cant give someone 'owner', if he is not in your organization. So instead I gave a 'WRITER' permission.

Comment: Consider posting an answer explaining how you solved this.